# I am facing an issue with my Gradle version whenever i want to generate a signed app

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

[Gradle Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wtkw.jpg)

I am facing the above error in Android Studio since a lot of time and I am unable to generate an App. I have update the Gradle version manually from the editor as you can see in the image below
[Gradle version I upgraded manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1zBv.jpg) but still it says to generate a signed apk you must update your Gradle version to 3.2.0 or higher. PLEASE SOMEONE HELP ME...

I have tried anything but nothing works for me